# Get longer calculation-output of log() in C++

Tags: c++, math

I need to get a more precise output of the math function log().
I want to obtain the 2. and 10th digit of the number.

My test code looks like this:

```
#include "string"
#include <sstream>

double temp_number = log(10.0);
std::ostringstream strs;
strs << temp_number;
std::string str = strs.str();
std::cout << str << "\n";
```

I'm casting the double to string because I don't know how to obtain numbers by index in double's. Anyhow, when casting to string and even if I check the output before with `cout` the calculation get's rounded to 6 digits which is clearly not precise enough.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You'll need to work out some algorithm to calculate the digits you need, rather than calling the `log()` function.    Also, your question has nothing to do with the tag "logging".   Pick a better tag.

Comment: Must be some type of autofill .. I clearly said log, without "ging" .. You have any suggestions on how to get the numbers? Other programming languages are fare more precise when calling log()
I'm trying to port some code from Autoit to C++ ..

Comment: If the other language works with floating point, it won't be any more or less accurate than C++'s `log()` function - the accuracy is determined by the floating point representation, and algorithms in hardware for computing the logarithm.    If it has some other representation, and computes to an arbitrary number of decimal places, it probably uses some variant of the spigot algorithm.

Comment: Yes, the other language is way more precise than C++, so the error is within C++. There must be a way to use the build in log() function with an longer output ..? I don't want to rewrite the math operations behind this and I'm pretty sure I won't be able either ..

Comment: Since `10.0` is of type `double`, as is `temp_number`, you should be able to get 15 valid digits out of `log()`. E.g. `#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
int main (void) { double temp_number = log(10.0); printf ("%23.16e\n", temp_number); return EXIT_SUCCESS; }` prints `2.3025850929940459e+000`, while true value is 2.30258509299404568401799....

Comment: You're right njuffa. You code shows correct results. So std::cout just rounds the number for some reason I don't understand .. But when transforming the double to string it get's rounded as well .. When looking at str.size() it returns the rounded size of the double .. I don't understand why this would happen?

Comment: It's just a setting of default precision on output.

Answer (score 0):

Correct way is:

```
#include "string"
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>      // std::setprecision

double temp_number = log(10.0);
std::ostringstream strs;
strs << std::setprecision(15) << temp_number;
std::string str = strs.str();
std::cout << str << "\n";
```

Usind `std::setprecision(15)` helps to get the correct values